# Android Splash background Image

Tags: android

I am using [this](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/create-a-splash-screen-on-android-the-right-way-93d6fb444857) example to create splash screen for my android app. But the background image is stretching. Below is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/splash_portrait"  />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

How to proportionately scale the bitmap?

Answer (score 3):

The image you use should be a Vector Image.

Vector Images can resize at will and still retain clarity.

If you use normal images, no matter how you implement it, it will either stretch or shrink depending on the mobile screen.

Comment: Thanks @Sriram. How to convert png to vector? What is the extension of vector image? .svg?

Comment: You cant use .svg in Android. You will need a .xml image to use. I'm not sure if you can convert a PNG to an XML vector image. The best thing to do is to create a new vector image using photoshop or something other.

Comment: You **can** use .svg in Android. Right click drawable-folder -> new -> vector asset -> Local file (SVG, PSD)